# Displaying page in a frame - Yandex Metrica Webvisor

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers, yandex

I have a problem with Yandex Metrica - the webvisor function isn't working on all pages. Instead, it displays

"Not possible to replay visit on the given page. 
Possible reasons:
Counter code not configured
Displaying this page in a frame is forbidden"

Is there any way to bypass it? Tried X-Frame-Options Allow-from, but didn't work and I heard it isn't supported in many browsers.

Best regards,
Kuba

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all AdBlocker Plugins like AdBlock Plus or uBlock Origin. The Session Replays open in a new window and the domain changes from yandex.com to webvisor.com. So be sure to disable your AdBlocker Plugins for the domain Webvisor.com.

Hope that helps! Worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

in `.htaccess` file add

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: This doesnt help at all.